# Django testing, need fixtures for picture

Tags: django, fixtures, django-testing

So I'm doing some unittests on a particular Django app. When in a testing environment, I basically create a fresh database with my own data.

In a normal non-testing environment, I load up a page with a person's details. When this happens a signal is sent and it retrieves the person's picture (which is in a different app) and some other certain data (which is also in a different app).

So in my testing I have used fixtures to get all of the relevant data for the people who I create in the testing database. But I can't work out how to do this with the pictures...Can I create two lots of 'fixtures'?

The first test I am trying is ever so simple

```
resp = self.client.get(reverse('person_detail', kwargs={'id': 'blobby'}))
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

So 'person_detail' is a named url I have and it successfully gets the "other data" using the fixtures, but I somehow need it to get a picture as my test(s) fail with the message 'Pic matching query does not exist'. Even just giving all of my test database people a default picture would be great. Anyone got any ideas about how to approach this? The pictures are saved on file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TestCase class, include a setUp() function that pulls in the pictures for everyone.  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/)

Comment: Ok, so that seems sensible but how do I instruct Django as to the location of the file? Do I just create an instance of my Pic model (one of whose files is presumably the location on file - just when I do that, I get an access denied message, so maybe that's a different problem)

Comment: Right, you can create instances of the Pic model and save them (to the test db).